# How to run kubernetes commands on different host than one originally used?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, gcloud

After successfully launching a gcloud or aws cluster then populating it with kubernetes Service + Deployment commands like

```
kubectl create -f my-deployment.yaml
```

all is well ONLY if I stay on that same machine ... However how do I continue interacting with same deployed cluster from a different local host ?  ... I am trying to avoid the dreaded :

```
kubectl get pods
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***For Amazon aws*** just authenticate using

```
export     AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(cat ${AWS_ACCOUNT_CONFIGDIR}/id)
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(cat ${AWS_ACCOUNT_CONFIGDIR}/key)

$(aws ecr get-login --region ${AWS_REGION} )
```

then issue kubectl commands as though you deployed your cluster from this other host

---

***For google cloud*** :  just login to gcloud on that different local host to retrieve cluster credentials

```
gcloud container --project ${PROJECT_ID}  clusters get-credentials ${GKE_CLUSTER} --zone ${GKE_ZONE}
```

then kubernetes commands will work ... as per

```
kubectl get pods
NAME                                    READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
chainsaw-deployment-2102970301-q5hyn    2/2       Running   0          2h
mongo-controller-81c3m                  1/1       Running   0          2h
```

Comment: Yep, that's the solution. Used to be you have to be in the same zone long time ago, but it is fixed now, I believe. Just get credentials and you good to go

Comment: It works for any zone if you add `--zone=${ZONE}` to the command regardless of the default zone set in your gcloud configuration.